# The best way to search string in BeatifulSoup.findAll('a')

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Guys please help me with next problem.
I need to find links with some key (string) and I used next code:

```
import  urllib2, re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'http://5pd.ru'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.findAll('a')
for link in soup.findAll('a'): 
    if '5' in link:
            print link
```

It doesn't return anything

But in this example:

```
site_list = ['http://extra1.ru/', 'http://5pd.ru/', 'http://google.ru/', 'http://fun.ru/']
for i in site_list:
    if '5' in i: 
        print i
```

It returned correct link

I just want to understand the most correct way to verify that link contain my string.
Maybe I should make smth with soup.findAll('a')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

link is not string. use link['href'] instead of link inside for loop or force conversion to string with str(link)

Comment: thank you, Thats was before, but I seems to stupid and forgot about it. But what type of a object has link, without ['href']?

Comment: print link.__class__  <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>

Answer (score 2):

findAll() with regular expression:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('5')):
    print link['href']
```